# How to nest a table, or anything else, inside align* or flalign*?

Tags: tables, align

This is my first day with latex and the basics aren't hard to pick up, but if I want to do anything more than default formatted formulas it's taking me forever to figure out how it works.

What I'm trying to do now is type up my homework. I want question numbers vertically aligned to the left and the answers are all tables. So, something like:

```
23a)  (table here)

  b)  (table here)

etc.
```

My code snippet is below and I just can't get it to compile. I get multiple "missing `$` inserted" or "extra `}`, or forgotten `$`" errors. I have no idea what I'm doing and I can't find any remotely usable documentation.

```
\begin{flalign*}
\textbf{32a)} & 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        p & \neg p & p \rightarrow \neg p \\ \hline
        \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\
        \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
    \end{tabular} &\\
\textbf{c)} &
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        p & q & p \lor q & p \oplus (p \lor q) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} &\\
\end{flalign*}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `tabular' by`array'.

```
\begin{flalign*}
\textbf{32a)} & 
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
    p & \neg p & p \rightarrow \neg p \\ \hline
    \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\
    \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
\end{array} &\\
\text{\bf c)} &
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
    p & q & p \lor q & p \oplus (p \lor q) \\ \hline
\end{array} &\\
\end{flalign*}
```

Comment: `\textbf` is perfectly legal in math mode; on the other hand, `\bf` has been deprecated for more than twenty years

Answer (score 1):

Rather use a list to enumerate your answers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\TRUE}{\text{T}}
\newcommand{\FALSE}{\text{F}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[\bfseries 32a)] 
    $\begin{array}[t]{|c|c|c|}
      p & \neg p & p \rightarrow \neg p \\
      \hline
      \TRUE  & \FALSE & \FALSE \\
      \FALSE & \TRUE  & \TRUE  \\
      \TRUE  & \TRUE  &        \\
      \FALSE & \FALSE &
    \end{array}$

  \item[\bfseries c)]
    $\begin{array}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}
      p & q & p \lor q & p \oplus (p \lor q) \\
      \hline
      \TRUE  & \TRUE  & & \\
      \TRUE  & \FALSE & & \\
      \FALSE & \TRUE  & & \\
      \FALSE & \FALSE & &
    \end{array}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I also switched to an `array` since the content is math-specific. Also for consistency and convenience, defined `\TRUE` and `\FALSE` to represent the truth values of the variable(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\begin{flalign*}
\textbf{32a)} &
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        p & $\neg$ p & p $\rightarrow \neg$p \\ \hline
        \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\
        \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
    \end{tabular} &\\
\textbf{c)} &
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        p & q & p $\lor$ q & p $\oplus$ (p $\lor$ q) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} &\\
\end{flalign*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Werner answer, but with tabular:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{32a)}]\quad 
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
        p & $\neg$ p    & p $\rightarrow \neg$p \\ \hline
        T & F           & F \\
        F & T           & T \\
    \end{tabular}
\item[\textbf{c)}]\quad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}
        p & q & p $\lor$ q & p $\oplus$ (p $\lor$ q) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

*Addendum:*
With use of package `enumitem`, the use of list is even simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section*{Task}
\begin{itemize}[font=\bfseries,labelwidth=2em,labelsep=2em,leftmargin=!]
\item[32a)]
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
        p & $\neg$ p    & p $\rightarrow \neg$p \\ \hline
        T & F           & F \\
        F & T           & T \\
    \end{tabular}
    
    some comment about solution in table (if it is necessary) 
\item[c)]
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}
        p & q & p $\lor$ q & p $\oplus$ (p $\lor$ q) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

IN this case, if the task number is longer as it in example, you need to encrease `labelwidth`. For exaple for task number `123)` a suitable `labelwidth` is `3em`.